# How can I fill a TListBox with the names of the .DBF files in a Folder?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I want to fill this ListBox with the names of the .DBF files in a Folder.

For example: I have the Folder `C:/Kassendaten` containing `IArtikel.dbf`, `IBediener.dbf`, etcetera

I need this to let the user select a dbf file.

I new in Delphi and don't know how I an do this.

Comment: Drop a `TFileListBox` on a form and set its `Directory` to the folder of your choice and its `Mask` to `*.dbf`. I know, I know, it's from Win 3.1 control tab :-)

Comment: Really though, a list view is far more appropriate for this task than a list box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
procedure FillFiles(Strings: TStrings; const strDirectory, strExtension: string);
var
  sr: TSearchRec;
begin
  if FindFirst(strDirectory + '\*.' + strExtension, faAnyFile, sr) = 0 then
    try
      Strings.BeginUpdate;
      try
        Strings.Clear;
        repeat
          Strings.Add(sr.Name);
        until FindNext(sr) <> 0;
      finally
        Strings.EndUpdate;
      end;
    finally
      FindClose(sr);
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FillFiles(lstFiles.Items, 'C:\', 'dbf');
end;
```

Comment: really do not need, I changed the answer

Comment: Passella, good question! Well, not necessarily in this case (since the only risk here is that the list box will raise a `EOutOfResources` exception when adding items).

Comment: I would rather change `lstFiles: TListBox` parameter to `TStrings` so it will be more generic and could be used with any `TStrings` descendant. Also, I dont see the need for both `strDirectory, strExtension` simply provide `sPath`. usage would be `FillFiles(lstFiles.Items, 'C:\*.dbf')`

Comment: @kobik I made that change

Answer (score 4):

Use the functionality available in the `IOUtils` unit, and the arrays that are declared in the `Types` unit. Add both of those units to your `implementation` users clause, and then something like this should work:

```
var
  aFiles: TStringDynArray;
  sFile: String;
begin
  aFiles := TDirectory.GetFiles('C:\Kassendaten', '*.dbf');
  ListBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for sFile in aFiles do
      ListBox1.Items.Add(sFile);
  finally
    ListBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: +1 for a clean approach to the coding. It makes me sad that the designers of `TStrings` did not have the sense to make `AddStrings` receive an open array. Had they done so you could write: `ListBox1.Items.AddStrings(TDirectory.GetFiles(...))`. It is also terribly disappointing that `IOUtils`, such a prominent unit, uses the hopelessly inconvenient `TStringDynArray` rather than the useful `TArray<string>`.

Comment: Thanks. I agree with both points. An overloaded `AddStrings` that would accept an array would have been great, and wouldn't have broken anything. I don't have a major issue with the `TStringDynArray`, but the generics would have been nice.

Comment: What surprises me is why the `GetFiles` function returns the items also with the path (which is passed). I would expect just the file names...

Answer (score 3):

The unit IOUTILS.pas has a class TDirectory with methods to get a directory listing in an array of strings.
The TListbox has a property Items that represent strings for the rows in the listbox.

That should help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic function, `GetFileNames`, that I always use for similar tasks:

```
//Returns a list of all the filenames matching the searchpath criteria.
//Note: Free the returned TStringList when finished with it.
function GetFileNames(const SearchPath : String): TStringList;
var
  SearchRec:TSearchRec;
  Path: string;
begin
  result := TStringList.Create;
  try
    // Extract directory path
    path := ExtractFilePath(SearchPath);

    if not DirectoryExists(Path) then exit;

    // Find files
    if FindFirst(SearchPath,faAnyFile,SearchRec) = 0 then
      try
        repeat
          result.Add(Path+SearchRec.Name);
        until FindNext(SearchRec) <> 0;
      finally
        FindClose(SearchRec);
      end;
  except
    result.Free;
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

### How to use

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.Text := 'C:\MyFavoriteDir\*.dpr'
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  FileNames : TStrings;
begin
  FileNames := GetFileNames(Edit1.Text);
  try
    ListBox1.items.Assign(FileNames);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(FileNames);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You must only call `FindClose` if `SearchRec` is valid, that is the call to `FindFirst` succeeded. You will need to put the `try` in a different place. You should also use `repeat/until` here to avoid duplication. And you'll leak the string list if the function throws. A better interface is to allow the caller to supply a `TStrings` instance that can be populated by the function. That is much more general purpose. For instance in your "how to use" section you can avoid creating and destroying a temp string list. Which will, incidentally, also puts the try in the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks for your QA feedback David. I've modified my code regarding FindClose and repeat/until. You are right about the leak an exception IS raised! I do however not understand why because I thought it was enough to create the TStringList object in the begining of the func? I.e. result:=TStringList.Create;

Comment: Your modifications address the duplication but nothing else. Let me edit to show what I mean. That will be easiest. But it would still be better for caller to provide a `TStrings` instance. Then the caller could pass `ListBox1.Items`.

Comment: OK, I see what you have done. But why isn't there an object becase I have called result := TStringList.Create;?

Comment: Even with your suggestion I get an Unexpected Memory Leak when closing app.
---------------------------
An unexpected memory leak has occurred. The unexpected small block leaks are:
85 - 92 bytes: TStringList x 1

Comment: Instead of a function that returns a new object, have a procedure that is passed a `TStrings`. Then populate that. And as for the memory leak, that one is on you!

Comment: @Passella Not so.  Assign won't be called because of the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
{code}
    var s: string;
    begin
      s := 'c:\windows\*.bmp'#0;
      ListBox1.Perform(LB_DIR, DDL_READWRITE, LongInt(@s[1]));
    end;
{code
```